# Graphs Approaching Asymptotes

Tags: functions, asymptotics, graphing-functions

I've been wondering this for a while. For graphs that approach asymptotes, are there certain formulas that can determine the distance between the graph and the asymptote as $x$ gets infinitely small or large?

Comment: For horizontal and vertical asymptotes, just "subtract" the equations: So if you have $f(x) = \frac{1}{x-2}$, then you have a vertical asymptote at $x=2$. So the distance function would be $| 2 - x|$ (if you want to find the distance from the asymptote for some input $x$)

Comment: For the vertical asymptote, don't you mean the distance is $|2-x_0|$ instead of $|2-f(x_0)|$?

Comment: I edited my comment; now it should be correct.

Comment: That's the same as $x_0$. I don't see why adding the extra functions helps explain it better.

Answer (score 2):

To summarize what the commenters said, you can always subtract either the $x$-value or the value of the function to find the distance.

In other words, if you have some function $f(x)$ that has a horizontal asymptote at $y=a$ and/or a vertical asymptote at $x=b$, the distance of the function from the horizontal asymptote will always be $|a-f(x)|$, and the distance of the function from the vertical asymptote will always be $|b-x|$.

---

If we want to make things more interesting and talk about oblique asymptotes, the problem gets much more complicated, since the distances we'll now be concerned with will no longer be perfectly vertical or horizontal. They will, however, be orthogonal to the oblique asymptote, which is the principle off of which I based [this Desmos page](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ddunsafwpz).

It involves formulas that are probably too long to fit on a single line here, but I did find a way to find the distance between a general rational function of the form $$f(x)=\frac{a^2+bx+c}{dx+h}$$ (using $h$ there to avoid confusion with the base of the natural logarithm and the functions I named $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ in Desmos) and its oblique asymptote.

Comment: Wow, I asked this over three years ago. I think what I meant back then was if there was a way to find the closest distance between a graph and the asymptote, not the vertical distance.

Comment: And somehow, no one answered it until today! What do you mean by "closest distance" if not "vertical distance?" (Assuming we're talking about horizontal asymptotes, that is.)

Comment: Ah, I think I forgot to specify diagonal asymptotes. That was what I had in mind when I asked the question but I see how it could easily be read as horizontal asymptotes.

Comment: That does change things! Also makes the problem much more interesting. I'll see what I can come up with.

Comment: Maybe we can start by looking the graph of $y=\dfrac{x^2+2x-1}{x-1}$. That's the kind of graph I had in mind when I first thought of this question.

Comment: I think I've got something that better answers your original question; give me a minute to edit my answer.